# Getting live_server fixture with Django test working

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-django

I would like to use `pytest`, `pytest-django`, and `pytest-selenium` together to test my Django application functionality.  If I start the server manually with `python manage.py runserver`, and manually input the URL, it works fine.

The `live_server` fixture from `pytest-django` is supposed to start a server process in the background that I could use, but it's not working. Instead of a passing test, I get "The requested resource was not found on this server."

Here are the relevant sections of my files:

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = chatsite_api.settings.test
addopts = --liveserver localhost:8080  --cov=. --cov-report=html --driver Firefox
```

test_pages.py

```
import pytest

def test_homepage(selenium, live_server):
    selenium.get(live_server.url)
    assert "Django: the Web framework" in selenium.title
```

And chatsite_api.settings.test.py

```
from .dev import *  # NOQA

DATABASES = {"default": {"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3", "NAME": ":memory:"}}

DEBUG = True
```

As I said, the tests run fine when I start the server myself, but the live_server fixture doesn't seem to be doing what it's supposed to. I have verified that the `live_server.url` is being set according to the `addopts` line in pytest.ini, but that is as far as I've gotten.

Comment: Are you testing the default landing page? It is only shown for demo purposes and won't be displayed when the live server starts. Can you show your `urls.py` module?

Comment: If you need the default page, you can set it as the index page via `from django.views.debug import default_urlconf; urlpatterns = [path('', default_urlconf, name='index')]`

Comment: Duh. Thank you. Want to put this in an answer so I can credit you with fixing the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing against the default index page (the one with the "The install worked successfully! Congratulations!" greeting), it is only shown when running the development server with `DEBUG = True`. In particular, it won't be present in tests. If you want to use the view, you need to explicitly configure it in `urls` module like the other views:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from django.views.debug import default_urlconf


urlpatterns = [
    path('', default_urlconf, name='index'),
]
```